# checkBox ng-Repeat from controller-data not Rendering : AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am picking up checkbox Data from Controller file, but it is not rendering properly. Following is my html:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in People">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{x.id}}" >{{x.name}}<br/> 
    </tr>
</table>
<button>Click</button>
<script>
//Module Declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.People = [
        {name:"Peter",id:"201"},
        {name:"Lina",id:"202"},
        {name:"Roger",id:"203"}
    ];
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Expectation:**

3 rows of input checkboxes with names adjescent to them

**Result:**

[image]

There are no JS Errors. Can someone help me out what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a "td" tag : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Zonedark/t0k9f4dj/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in People">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{x.id}}" >{{x.name}}<br/> 
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button>Click</button>
<script>
//Module Declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
//Controller Declaration
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.People = [
        {name:"Peter",id:"201"},
        {name:"Lina",id:"202"},
        {name:"Roger",id:"203"}
    ];
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```